# How to join a number with the range of number from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the two following tables:

```
| ID  | Count |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | 45    |
| 2   | 5     |
| 3   | 120   |
| 4   | 87    |
| 5   | 60    |
| 6   | 200   |
| 7   | 31    |
```

```
| SizeName | LowerLimit | UpperLimit |
| -------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| Small    | 0          | 49         |
| Medium   | 50         | 99         |
| Large    | 100        | 250        |
```

Basically, one table specifies an unknown number of range names and their associated integer ranges. So a count range of 0 to 49 from the person table gets a `small` designation. 50-99 gets '`medium`' etc. I need it to be dynamic because I do not know the range names or integer values.

Can I do this in a single query or would I have to write a separate function to loop through the possibilities?

Comment: Are the ranges always mutually exclusive?

Comment: yes @VadimLanda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to join the tables, depending on if you want to keep values outside of your "range names", or not, you could use LEFT, or INNER join respectively.

```
SELECT A.id, A.Count, B.SizeName
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.id >= B.LowerLimit AND A.id < B.UpperLimit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`BETWEEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator in a `JOIN` like this:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.Count, b.SizeName
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.id BETWEEN b.LowerLimit AND b.UpperLimit
```